Reference request: When is the modular lambda function algebraic?
I read somewhere that said that the modular lambda function, defined as the ratio of two theta functions is algebraic whenever the parameter $\tau$ is defined over a number field, but I cannot find a reference for this.

It is equivalent to saying that the $j$-invariant is algebraic (since $j$ is a rational function of $\lambda$) which should be easier to find references on. But Wikipedia only claims this is true when $\tau$ is imaginary quadratic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Class_field_theory_and_j

As written in the previous comment, $\lambda(\tau)$ is algebraic if and only if $j(\tau)$ is algebraic. This is always true if $\tau$ is imaginary quadratic, but if $\tau$ is algebraic but not imaginary quadratic then $j(\tau)$ must be transcendental (see Transcendence properties on en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant). Also note that $j(\tau)$ can be algebraic for transcendental $\tau$ (in a sense this is the generic case).
